# Unable to view the webpage hosted on my ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I wanted to launch a little static website on an EC2 instance and I followed the following steps:

1. launched a t2.micro instance using console in us-east-1 region
2. attached an existing security group which allows http request, https and ssh.
3. logged in my ec2 through SSH and changed it into an apache web server using following commands:

commands:

```
#bin/bash
sudo su
yum update -y
yum install httpd -y
cd /var/www/html
```

4. Then I wrote a hello world html code in index.html file and started my web service

   `service httpd start`
   `chkconfig on`

Even after following all the above steps, when I open try to access the webpage by going to the public ipv4 address of my ec2 instance, I am getting a timout error.
Any idea what I might be missing here?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you open up security groups for your instance to access port 80?

Comment: Check inbound traffic HTTP/80 should be open in the SG.

Comment: If you SSH into the instance and then run `curl localhost`, does it show the page?

Comment: @jningthou I have the following ports opened to the world: 80 (http), 443(https) and ssh(22). But still, I couldn't access the public IP of launched EC2.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I performed the command `curl localhost` while being in directory /home/ec2-user. And I could see the HTML code written in my index.html (of /var/www/html). But when I go to public IP, it still timeouts.

Comment: @SidhantGupta, Are you using ACL or any OS level firewall?

Comment: @Riz, I have used only the default settings while launching my ec2 instance, except that I have used the existing security group. So, I haven't made use of any ACL or OS level firewall.

Comment: @SidhantGupta, Are you also accessing your webpage as `http` and not `https`? By default your browser opens the site as `https`.

Comment: @Riz, I have tried both the methods, tried accessing using http and https but both didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating new EC2 instance like below

- Lunch the same type of instance
- Add below script in user data to create HTML page

  #!/bin/bash

  ## Use this for your user data (script from top to bottom)

  ## install httpd

  yum update -y
  yum install -y httpd
  systemctl start httpd
  systemctl enable httpd
  echo "

  ### Hello World - $(hostname -f)

  " > /var/www/html/index.html
- After launching EC2, open that security group and add below HTTP rule

[image: security_group]

- At the end, manually type HTTP://your public address.  sometimes by default its shows with HTTPS so just ensure you are typing HTTP only.